# React Why won't my app render the updated state for google maps?

Tags: reactjs

My app only renders the initial value of my latitude/longitude state. I am trying to get it to render the updated state that I set to the users location with `navigator.geolocation`. I've tried some conditional logic but I still only get a map with lat=0, lng=0. Here is my Map Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";

export default function Map() {
  const [userLat, setUserLat] = useState(0);
  const [userLng, setUserLng] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    function updateUserLat() {
      //DIFFERENT CONDITIONS I'VE TRIED
      // if (userLat === 0 && userLng === 0) {
      //   return;
      // }
      // if (userLat === 0 && userLng === 0) {
      //   return null;
      // }
      //function updateUserLat(latValue){if(!latValue) return;}

      navigator &&
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          const coords = position.coords;
          setUserLat(coords.latitude);
          console.log(userLat);
        });

      return userLat;
    }

    function updateUserLng() {
      //DIFFERENT CONDITIONS I'VE TRIED
      // if (userLat === 0 && userLng === 0) {
      //   return;
      // }
      // if (userLat === 0 && userLng === 0) {
      //   return null;
      // }
      //function updateUserLng(lngValue){if(!lngValue) return;}

      navigator &&
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          const coords = position.coords;
          setUserLng(coords.longitude);
          console.log(userLng);
        });

      return userLng;
    }
    updateUserLat();
    updateUserLng();
  }, [userLat, userLng]);

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={10}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: userLat, lng: userLng }}
    />
  );
}
```

Here is my App Component:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
} from "react-google-maps";
import Map from "./Map";

const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <MyMapComponent
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=API_KEY
      `}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are not using `useEffect()` correctly

your useEffect function are updating `userLang` and `userLat`, right ?

and `userLang` and `userLat` are states can only be changed by `setUserLang`

so if you need to trigger your useEffect you need to give it something that has changed in order to set the new `userLat`

```
useEffect(()=>{myfunction(){} 
  myFuncion();
},[thisVarActuallyChanges])
```

`thisVarActuallyChanges` is a variable that changes in order to re-trigger useEffect

for more clarfication watch Ben Awad 's video about useEffect [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1ZRyw7OtZs)

Comment: Thanks for the link and response. I think I am struggling with the `thisVarActuallyChanges` part. I just want the page to render first showing the useEffect logic with the new `setUserLat` and `setUserLng`  --not with the initial useState. I'll finish the video you sent though. thanks again